# Old questions at top of feed show being recently modified?

Tags: support, bug

I see years old questions at the top of my feed which show as being modified recently but nothing within the actual post shows evidence of that.

For example this question:
[Arduino CNC - which vacuum pump?](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/14658/arduino-cnc-which-vacuum-pump)

Is this a bug or is the question actually being “modified” such that it seems like a “new” question and is being kept to the top of the feed?

Answer (score 1):

This is just the [Community♦](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) user [bumping](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/48578/347987) questions with no accepted answer.

This is an automated means by which the site tries to call attention to questions which might need it. See the second link above for a description of the "rules of the game".